# JTable not updating values as new rows are added

Tags: java, swing, jtable

This is the screen of my system where it lists the available Magazines("revistas") and Books("livros") from ArrayLists of String[] containing Name,Availability,Code.

Everything is working fine, except the table is showing blank.

This is my class, I've cropped the variable declarations.

Function "listar" at the bottom is what loads the JTable with data.

I'm also confused on how to work with effective and good looking Panel layouts, if someone could give a side hint on that.

```
public class TelaListaDoc extends JPanel {

public TelaListaDoc(Biblioteca biblio) {

    this.biblioteca = biblio;
    this.inicializado = false;

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    cLayout = new CardLayout();

    panelMain = new JPanel();
    panelTable = new JPanel(cLayout);
    panelRevista = new JPanel();
    panelLivro = new JPanel();

    String[] nomes = {"Título", "Nº disponíveis", "Código"};
    modelLivro = new DefaultTableModel(nomes, 0);
    modelRevista = new DefaultTableModel(nomes, 0);

    tableRevista = new JTable(modelLivro);
    tableLivro = new JTable(modelRevista);

    botaoVoltar = new JButton("Voltar");
    botaoRevista = new JButton("Revistas");
    botaoLivro = new JButton("Livros");
    panelRevista.add(new JScrollPane(tableRevista));
    panelLivro.add(new JScrollPane(tableLivro));

    panelTable.add(panelRevista, "Revista");
    panelTable.add(panelLivro, "Livro");
    panelTable.setVisible(true);

    panelMain.add(botaoRevista);
    panelMain.add(botaoLivro);
    panelMain.add(panelTable);
    panelMain.add(botaoVoltar);

    panelMain.setVisible(true);
    add(panelMain);

    botaoVoltar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            biblioteca.chamaTelaBiblioteca();
        }
    });

    botaoLivro.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            cLayout.show(panelTable, "Livro");

        }
    });

    botaoRevista.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            cLayout.show(panelTable, "Revista");
        }
    });
}

public void listar(ArrayList<String[]> livros, ArrayList<String[]> revistas) {
    if (!this.inicializado) {  //If not initialized, only doing it once.

        this.livros = livros;
        this.revistas = revistas;
        for (String[] livro : this.livros) {
            modelLivro.addRow(livro);
        }
        for (String[] revista : this.revistas) {
            modelRevista.addRow(revista);
        }
        this.inicializado = true;
        modelLivro.fireTableDataChanged();
        modelRevista.fireTableDataChanged();
        panelLivro.setVisible(true);
        panelRevista.setVisible(true);

        cLayout.show(panelTable, "Revista");
    }

}

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: you put too much in the constructor

Comment: *"how to work with effective and good looking Panel layouts, if someone could give a side hint on that."* Do you have some idea of what a "good looking panel" looks like?

Comment: @MadProgrammer , by good looking I meant easily organized components,borders, etc.

Comment: You shouldn't call fireTableChanged directly

Comment: Have you tried - fireTableRowsInserted, on your table models?

Comment: Instead of using two tables, use a single table and switch the models, this will allow you to do away with the CardLayout

Comment: The problem you're having is, you adding botaoRevista and botaoLivro to panelMain, which means they no longer reside in panelTable. A component can have only a single parent, when you add a component to a new parent container, it is first removed from its current container

Comment: @MadProgrammer I didn't quite get the issue, what would be the fix?

Comment: Don't have two `JTable`'s have a single `JTable` and switch the models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you do...

```
panelRevista.add(new JScrollPane(tableRevista));
panelLivro.add(new JScrollPane(tableLivro));

panelTable.add(panelRevista, "Revista");
panelTable.add(panelLivro, "Livro");
```

which is fine, but then you do...

```
panelMain.add(botaoRevista);
panelMain.add(botaoLivro);
panelMain.add(panelTable);
panelMain.add(botaoVoltar);
```

Which removes `botaoRevista` and `botaoLivro` from `panelTable` leaving it blank, before they are added to `panelMain`.  A component can only reside within a single container. When you try and add a component to another container, it is first removed from it's current container.

A better solution would be to have a single `JTable` and simply change the models

Something like...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class TelaListaDoc extends JPanel {

    private DefaultTableModel modelLivro;
    private DefaultTableModel modelRevista;
    private JTable table;

    public TelaListaDoc(Biblioteca biblio) {

        this.biblioteca = biblio;
        this.inicializado = false;

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        panelMain = new JPanel();

        String[] nomes = {"Título", "Nº disponíveis", "Código"};
        modelLivro = new DefaultTableModel(nomes, 0);
        modelRevista = new DefaultTableModel(nomes, 0);

        table = new JTable(modelLivro);

        botaoVoltar = new JButton("Voltar");
        botaoRevista = new JButton("Revistas");
        botaoLivro = new JButton("Livros");

        panelMain.add(new JTable(model));
        panelMain.add(panelTable);
        panelMain.add(botaoVoltar);

        add(panelMain);

        botaoVoltar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                biblioteca.chamaTelaBiblioteca();
            }
        });

        botaoLivro.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                table.setModel(modelLivro);
            }
        });

        botaoRevista.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                table.setModel(modelRevista);
            }
        });
    }

    public void listar(ArrayList<String[]> livros, ArrayList<String[]> revistas) {
        if (!this.inicializado) {  //If not initialized, only doing it once.

            this.livros = livros;
            this.revistas = revistas;
            for (String[] livro : this.livros) {
                modelLivro.addRow(livro);
            }
            for (String[] revista : this.revistas) {
                modelRevista.addRow(revista);
            }
            this.inicializado = true;

            table.setModel(modelRevista);
        }

    }

}
```

As an example...